# SQLselect from multiple table

Tags: sql, select, left-join

Are 2 tables `users` and `phones`, in table `phones` are `id`,`user id`, `phone`, and `category`
I want select all from `users` and for each users phone which category is 1, but if user not have phone I want also select his without phone.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
   LEFT JOIN phones ON users.id = phones.id 
WHERE phones.category = 1
```

this select is only correct if `user` have `phone`, but if user not have phone it not select this users. How to change select that it select users also if `user` not havo `phone` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
Left JOIN phones 
ON users.id = phones.id and phones.category = 1
```

If you use where in left or right join than it will behave like inner join so try like above
or
You can try like this.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
Left JOIN phones 
ON users.id = phones.id where ( phones.category = 1 OR phones.category is null)
```

Comment: Although if you use the second one, put the OR condition in (). Trust me, when someone adds another contion to the query later you don't want it misinterpreted. I never use OR withouthparentheses.